# What is my favorite color?

Tags: riddle, rhyme, lateral-thinking, acrostic, limerick

Oh the sweet joys of favoritism! I have another puzzle for the community; as always good luck to you all, and I hope you enjoy it!

> Go to the bottom you'll see.
>
> Rounded but right there with me.
>
> Every morning,
>
> Each open warning,
>
> Negating the color you see.

---

### Hint

@LordFarquad has found the color but a full explanation is needed for acceptance. If @LordFarquad's answer isn't the first completely correct I will award them $+50$ bounty for the massive finds.

> Every morning, each open warning; view this surrounded with glory.

The following is a collection of correct information gathered from answers and comments.

> **Go to the bottom** - refers to the post and the bottom of the color wheel.
>  **Rounded, with me** - refers to the color wheel, and the word purple in my picture.
>  **Negating the color you see** - refers to the acrostic *GREEN* being a red herring.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is vastly different from my existing answer, so I'll add it in another one. I'm pretty sure this is it. Heavy thanks to @LordFarquaad for finding a LOT of this (and they deserve the bounty:)

As already confirmed:

> the acrostic of GREEN is a red herring, and the answer is purple.

Go to the bottom you'll see:

> The bottom of the color wheel is purple.

Rounded but right there with me:

> The word *purple* ***was*** in your profile picture. Also refers to the color wheel.

Every morning, each open warning:

> **Morning glory is a purple flower with poisonous seeds!** (thanks for the hint)

Negating the color you see:

> the acrostic is a red herring. Also, as pointed out in comments, in RGB the opposite of green is purple.

Comment: That's gotta be it! Great find!

Comment: The RGB opposite (negation?) of the acrostic is the answer, right?

Answer (score 15):

I think the answer is

> red

since

> the acrostic mentions 'GREEN' and red tends to be considered the negative of green in many contexts ('negating the color you see'), red is the lowest frequency visible color ('go to the bottom you'll see'), warnings are also often red ('each open warning'), and the sunlight in the early morning also has a red tint ('every morning'). Not positive about the second line's significance.

Comment: Second line could be something to do with rot13(pbybe jurry)

Comment: This was a really cool answer and taught me a few things, but unfortunately this is wrong. @Dorrulf is correct in their deduction on the second line; but there is more than one reference there. :)

Comment: I know this is wrong, but for the second line I was thinking that many of the lines were referring to a stoplight on a morning commute: "rounded but right there with me" was referring to the round shape of each lightbulb, "right there with me" would be that the RED light that is "negating the color you see" was right there with the acrostic GREEN (on the same stoplight), which is at "the bottom" of the traffic light. "Every morning" refers to the commute, "each open warning" could potentially be the amber/yellow light that separates the two. And the acrostic in itself was a RED herring. <3 :)

Answer (score 13):

I'm pretty sure the answer is

> Purple!

Go to the bottom you'll see.

> At the bottom of the post is your profile picture.

Rounded but right there with me.

> Rounded refers to the color wheel, while right there with me refers to the fact that right smack dab in the center of your profile picture is the word purple. Relating back to line 1, purple is at the bottom of the color wheel.

Every morning,

> The sunrise has purple in it

Each open warning,

> I'm not sure what to make of this line

Negating the color you see.

> The acrostic shows GREEN, but what's an acrostic compared to a sneakily hidden answer?

Comment: SO CLOSE! AHHH LOL +1

Comment: Negating was a reference to the acrostic. :) The true definition of negate is to nullify or make invalid.

Comment: @PerpetualJ I've updated it now! I'm not as certain about the "each open warning" line, but hopefully I'm a little closer

Comment: You've got the answer correct, but parts of your explanation are wrong. The first line is a dual reference, as is the second line. Both lines have the same references. Third line is a reference on its own, while the fourth and fifth combined refer to the third line and the acrostic.

Comment: For line 5, maybe consider rot13(eto naq plz pbybe inyhrf naq jung 0 (artngrq) inyhrf bs terra (npebfgvp) naq lryybj (fha) zrna va rnpu.) No idea on line 4 either, maybe just a warning of your line 3 answer, that what it's hiding is coming. Nice find on line 2!

Comment: @Dorrulf For line 5 that's going way to far lol but good lateral thinking!

Comment: Ohhhh, what about ubj gur jbeq checyr vf va pbagenfg gb gur terra onpxtebhaq bs lbh hfre vzntr? @PerpetualJ

Comment: With regards to the second clue: Checyr vf ncneg bs gur pbybhe jurry, ohg nyfb nccrnef va BC'f anzr ("vf evtug gurer jvgu zr") (https://www.rot13.com/)

Comment: For line 5, maybe you should pay attention to background

Comment: "Rounded refers to the color wheel" So one of the clues to what color it is is that it's a color? "while right there with me refers to the fact that right smack dab in the center of your profile picture is the word purple" Where? "Relating back to line 1, purple is at the bottom of the color wheel" There's One Official Color Wheel? Here the bottom is blue: https://www.teacherspayteachers.com/Product/Color-Wheel-Poster-Download-368856 Here it's green: https://weallsew.com/color-wheel-basics/ "The sunrise has purple in it" Sometimes. But it's more common to have red, yellow, and orange.

Comment: Great find indeed, I'll award the bounty in a few days! :)

Comment: @Acccumulation *Go to the bottom* tells you the color is at the bottom of the wheel. *right there with me* refers to it in my picture. If you go to my profile and zoom in on my picture it is under my hair near the center of the picture.

Comment: @PerpetualJ As I said, there is no standard orientation of the color wheel. You can't just assume that everyone will put purple on the bottom.

Answer (score 5):

Well,

> the acrostic is green. I'm not sure if this is the answer, a red herring or something else.

Comment: The acrostic is indeed a red herring. :)

Comment: @PerpetualJ "The acrostic is indeed a red herring" So you like red things?

Answer (score 5):

Is it

> Orange

Go to the bottom you'll see.

> Blue, at the bottom of the page

Rounded but right there with me.

> The blue around your user box, containing your profile picture.

Every morning,

> Orange in the sunrise

Each open warning,

> Warnings are often orange

Negating the color you see.

> The color I saw at the bottom of the page, and in your user box was blue. Orange is the complimentary colour of blue.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE @DanWood!   Nice Answer!

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> Blue

Go to the bottom you'll see.

> The deep blue sea.

Rounded but right there with me.

> It is a primary color on the color wheel.

Every morning,

> The blue sky.

Each open warning,

> ?

Negating the color you see.

> If you take the yellow background out of green(acrostic) you get blue.

Comment: Along these lines, for negating the colour you see rot13:vs lbh gnxr lryybj (onpxtebhaq pbybhe) bhg bs terra (npebfgvp) lbh trg oyhr

Comment: Ahh neat! I will add that :) Thanks @gabbo1092

Comment: Another great answer but no; the true answer will explain every line without question. As I stated, there are two references in line two; one discovered, the other is a lot harder to find and requires literal thinking, yet perhaps some lateral thinking. :)

Comment: Well, I didn't say you couldn't combine lines lol I just said you won't have any doubts on the subject. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to go with:

> Orange

Why?:

> "Go to the bottom you'll see." I'm assuming refers to the last line of the poem.  or the bottom of the Puzzling page. 
>  "Rounded but right there with me." An orange is round.
>  "Every morning," Sunrises are often orange.
>  "Each open warning," In code and other places, warnings are often highlighted in orange, rather than red for errors.
>  "Negating the color you see." The color I see in the acrostic is green, and the color at the bottom of the Puzzling page is also green (kind of circling back to the first line), so negating this would be orange, since it's across the pigment color wheel from green.

After some extra thought, I'm probably wrong, or at least my reasoning is, but no one else is right yet, so why not give this a chance?  (I previously deleted this answer, because of my probable bad reasoning.)

Answer (score 2):

The first and second line might refer to

> the blue(ish) border around the OP's name box (whatever the official name of that StackExchange UI element might be). It's *below* the text and it's around the OP's image ("*rounded*" and "*right there with me*").

Comment: Oh aren't you on fire! Welcome to Puzzling.SE! I suggest digging deeper into this! :)

Answer (score 0):

is it

> yellow

because:

> The riddle is written on yellow background;
>  "rounded but right here with me" the background is close to the text, around.;
>  warnings are yellow;
>  sun is yellow;

sorry for formatting issue, im new here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's:

> GREEN

why:

> G <-- o to the bottom you'll see.
>
> R <-- ounded but right there with me.
>
> E <-- very morning,
>
> E <-- ach open warning,
>
> N <--egating the color you see.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is:

> GREEN

Go to the bottom you'll see.

> At the bottom of the flower you will see sepal

Rounded but right there with me.

> Sepals are rounded and will be always with the flower

Every morning,

> Every morning flower opens

Each open warning,

> Flower opens with red color

Negating the color you see.

> Negating the color green we see red

Answer (score -3):

> Yellow 
>  Adding to the existing answers: Every morning i pee (yellow)

Edit: Thanks for the edit, was in the process of figuring it out myself, sorry about that XD

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE. You should check to see other answers to make sure someone else hasn't already said the answer you plan to or else there would be a lot of repeats present which doesn't add anything new or helpful. If you would like some more guidance on how this site works (and get your first badge) go through the tour in this link: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour